# ANTLR mismatched input 'foo(some_foo)' expecting {'foo'}

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a parser using ANTLR and am now at the stage of testing my parser/lexer.
I stumbled over a strange bug while trying to parse basically a variable assignment. (Like this)

`Foo = mpsga(LT);`

I get the error : `mismatched input 'line 1:6 mismatched input 'mpsga(LT)' expecting 'mpsga'`

This is especially strange for when I remove the brackets (or the argument `LT`),
the parser recognizes `mpsga` and it only misses the brackets (or the argument).

---

My Grammar looks something like this:

### Lexer

```
lexer grammar FooLexer;

COMMENT
:
    '#' ~[\r\n]* -> channel ( HIDDEN )
;


NEWLINE
:
    (
        '\r'? '\n'
        | '\r'
    )+ -> channel ( HIDDEN )
;


EQUALSSIGN
:
    '='
;

SEMICOLON
:
    ';'
;

MPSGA_255_1
:
    'LT'
;

MPSGA
:
    'mpsga'
;

WHITESPACE
:
    (
        ' '
        | '\t'
    )+ -> channel ( HIDDEN )
;

BRACKET_OPEN
:
    '('
;

BRACKET_CLOSED
:
    ')'
;

VAR
:
    [a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*
;
```

### Parser

```
parser grammar FooParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = FooLexer;
}

stmt_block
:
    stmt_list EOF
;

stmt
:
    VAR EQUALSSIGN expr SEMICOLON NEWLINE?
;

stmt_list
:
    stmt
    | stmt_list stmt
;

expr
:
     extvar
;

extvar
:

    MPSGA BRACKET_OPEN mpsga_field BRACKET_CLOSED

;

mpsga_field
:

    MPSGA_255_1
;
```

---

---

When I try to parse this `Foo = mpsga(LT);` in Java i get the error.
Any help is appreciated!

## Edit:

My Parse hierachy looks like the following:

> Foo = mpsga(LT);

```
stmt_block
->stmt_list:1
-->stmt
--->"Foo"
--->"="
--->expr
---->extvar
----->"mpsga(LT)"
---->";"
-><EOF>
```

> Foo = mpsga(LT;

```
stmt_block
->stmt_list:1
-->stmt
--->"Foo"
--->"="
--->expr
---->extvar
----->"mpsga"
----->"("
----->mpsga_field
------>"LT"
----->"<missing ')'>"
---->";"
-><EOF>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I solved the problem. For anyone experiencing the same issue: I had some Lexer rules that were ambiguous for the `mpsga` part.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. The input `Variable = foo(some_foo);` is properly parsed.

Comment: @BartKiers I updated the question. This is now my smallest example that still produces the error.

Comment: If I add the `SEMICOLON` to your lexer grammar, the input `Foo = mpsga(LT);` is, again, properly parsed with ANTLR 4.7.2. Parse tree is: https://ibb.co/HxgX8Xt

Comment: @BartKiers Strange. What are you using to parse it? Looks like the IntelliJ ANTLR plugin. 
I'm using the "test rule" feature of that plugin right now and it still gives me `line 1:6 mismatched input 'mpsga(LT)' expecting 'mpsga'`

Comment: Yes IntelliJ's ANTLR plugin. Here it is: https://ibb.co/6Pf4Bc4

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks. I just restarted my IntelliJ (which I did twice before) and now the minimal example actually works. I guess i now need to find the difference to my actual code. But thanks ^^

Comment: Okay i think i know what the issue is. There seems to be a bug in the ANTLR Plugin. I get the error , restart my InteliiJ and the error is gone.

Comment: No problem @Jakob

Answer (score 1):

It's the argument: your grammar accepts 'foo' or 'foo2' as constants, not some_foo.

Comment: Thanks for the quick Response, that was a typo. I fixed the question ^^

Comment: Yes, the typo was in the question, not in my grammar.